Restsharp Incorrect Response
Restsharp 112.0.0 is not returning response in expected format, while curl, postman, C# HTTP client is do.
so below is the expected format (which is postman, curl or rest of the utilities giving)
{
    "OutputParameters": {
        "XXEGFIN_AP_INVOICE_PKG-24CREATE": {
            "XXEGFIN_AP_INVOICE_PKG-24CREATE_ITEM": [
                {
                    "INVOICENUMBER": "",
                    "CURRENCYCODE": "",
                    "AMOUNT": "",
                    "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
                    "ERRORDETAILS": "",
                    "RESPONSEID": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

while using restsharp getting
{
    "OutputParameters": {
        "XXEGFIN_AP_INVOICE_PKG-24CREATE": {
            "XXEGFIN_AP_INVOICE_PKG-24CREATE_ITEM": {
                "INVOICENUMBER": "",
                "CURRENCYCODE": "",
                "AMOUNT": "",
                "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
                "ERRORDETAILS": "",
                "RESPONSEID": ""
            }
        }
    }
}

check "XXEGFIN_AP_INVOICE_PKG-24CREATE_ITEM" array vs object
Why is it so..
Any help really appreciated
expected response in below format
{
    "OutputParameters": {
        "XXEGFIN_AP_INVOICE_PKG-24CREATE": {
            "XXEGFIN_AP_INVOICE_PKG-24CREATE_ITEM": [
                {
                    "INVOICENUMBER": "",
                    "CURRENCYCODE": "",
                    "AMOUNT": "",
                    "STATUS": "SUCCESS",
                    "ERRORDETAILS": "",
                    "RESPONSEID": ""
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

